# Comparing class instances and attaining cumulative "score"

Tags: python, class, comparison, subclassing

So, I have two instances of a class Person and I am trying to do some comparisons. `sun`is one of several attributes of each instance is defined by two randomly generated numbers. I have the following questions... Is creating a subclass like `Match` the right way to go about setting up this comparison? And I want an `overall` "score" compiled at the end of this comparison, can I do that without the for-loop?

```
Person1 = Person("Person1")
Person2 = Person("Person2")


class Match(Person):

    overall = 0

    def __init__(self, Person1, Person2):
        self.Person1 = Person1
        self.Person2 = Person2

    def suns (self): 
        if abs(Person1.sun - Person2.sun) == 2 or 4 or 8 or 10:
            overall += 4

        elif abs(Person1.sun - Person2.sun) == 3 or 9: 
            overall -= 6

        elif abs(Person1.sun - Person2.sun) == 6:
            overall += 3

        else:
            overall += 0

print Match.overall
```

**EDIT**
To clarify what I am trying to do... I have some basic understanding of how the astrological birth chart compatibility services work and just for fun and practice I want to make a very basic version of that program run. For now, all the data is randomly generated and no user input is needed. Here is what the Person class looks like

```
from random import randint
from decimal import Decimal

def randomDecimal(a,b):
    return (randint(int(a), int(100.0 * b)))/100.0

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.sun = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30)) 
        self.moon = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30)) 
        self.mercury = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30))
        self.venus = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30))
        self.mars = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30))

    def printer(self):
        print "your Sun is in %f, at %f degrees" % (self.sun[0], self.sun[1])
        print "your Moon is in %f, at %f degrees" % (self.moon[0], self.moon[1])
            #and so on and so forth for the printer
```

Comment: What you are asking is quite open-ended, there are many different approaches. IMO, I would go with a simple function that takes two Persons.

Comment: Why is `Match` a subclass of `Person`?

Comment: Is a "Match" used in the context of a "Football match" where two people play against each other or is it a "Dating match" where two people are compared? You need to add a lot more context to explain what you are try to do here.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr think "dating match".

Comment: @alKid I want to compare attributes of two instances and not sure how else to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare two people, the comparison itself isn't also a person.

[Python classes have special methods you can overide that allow inbuilt python equalities](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to work.

For example:

```
class Person():
    __init__(self, name="Sinead OConnor", etc...):
        # boiler plate goes here
        self.name = name

    __eq__(self, anotherPerson):
        return False # Perople are wonderful and unique and have no equal

    __cmp__(self,anotherPerson):
        return anotherPerson == "You" # Nothing compares too you!
```

These will then allow you to do things like:

```
> a = Person(a)
> b = Person(b)
> a == b
False
```

Obviouusly, how to compare people is difficult and application specific, but once the logic is in it makes sence.

For your work, where you need to compare to people in the abstract "are they a good fit" sence, `**cmp** won't work as thats just is one thing greater than, less than or equal to another.

In those cases, you can do the following

```
class Person():
    delta = 100 # How close do 2 things need to be to be a good match
    __init__(self, name="Sinead OConnor", etc...):
        # boiler plate goes here
        self.name = name

    def loveOfPowerBallads(self,myRank):
        if 0<myRank<100:
            raise OutOfRange # Or whatever
        self.rankPowerBallads = myRank

    def isGoodMatch(self,otherPerson):
        return (self.rankPowerBallads - other.rankPowerBallads) ^ 2 < Person.delta
```

Then:

```
> ls = Person("legoStormtrooper")
> ls.loveOfPowerBallads(95)
> lp = Person("Lame Person")
> ls.loveOfPowerBallads(30)
> ls.isGoodMatch(lp)
False
```

#### Edit: Making it more specific for you (although the principle is the same):

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.sun = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30)) 
        self.moon = (randomDecimal(1, 12), randomDecimal(0, 30)) 
        # etc...

    def compare(self,other):
        overall = 0
        if abs(self.sun - other.sun) in [2,4,8,10]:
            overall += 4
        elif abs(self.sun - other.sun) in [3,9]: 
            overall -= 6
        elif abs(self.sun - other.sun) == 6:
            overall += 3
        else:
            overall += 0
        return overall
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you are trying to show me, but I don't think that it's applicable to what I am trying to do. I have updated the first message that explains it in more detail

Comment: @sivanes I've updated it to be closer to your code, but the principle is basically the same. When comparing two things, the comparator usually isn't a new object, and can be don't by calling one objects method with another object as an argument.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I am, just curious - did you notice this line __if abs(self.sun - other.sun) == 2 or 4 or 8 or 10:__

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this line

```
if abs(self.sun - other.sun) == 2 or 4 or 8 or 10:
```

actually means

```
if (abs(self.sun - other.sun) == 2) or 4 or 8 or 10:
```

Any non-empty value is regarded as *True*. so this expression will be always *True*. The proper form

```
if abs(self.sun - other.sun) in (2, 4, 8, 10):
```

The same goes fp the second *if* too