# Same method used on different variables

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

Let's say that I have a class and a method within it like below. What if I want to do the same thing to the pairs of self.two[0] and other.two[0] and whatever else I may need? What would go in the place of self.one[0] and other.one[0] in the method definition and how would I call this method?

UPDATED to give a better idea of what I have so far

```
class OurClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.one = (x, y) 
        self.two = (a, z)
         # and so on

    def ourmethod(self, other):
        overall = 0 
        if abs(self.one[1] - other.one[1]) <= 10:
            if abs(self.one[0] - other.one[0]) in [2, 4, 8, 10]:
                overall += 4                
            elif abs(self.one[0] - other.one[0]) in [3, 9]: 
                overall -= 6                
            elif abs(self.one[0] - other.one[0]) == 6:
                overall += 3                        
            elif abs(self.one[0] - other.one[0]) == 0:
                overall += 6        
            else:
                overall += 0
        else:
            overall += 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `one`, `two`, etc. attributes, rather than a list? Also, could you give an example of what `ourmethod` might be in an actual program, so it's easier to tell what you need?

Comment: @user2357112 Absolutely, I was asking something else earlier here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986086/comparing-class-instances-and-attaining-cumulative-score) , and posted most of the code. Obviously there were a lot of mistakes there that I have now corrected, but the main idea is the same. The method does stuff similar to 'def suns'

Comment: @sivanes It's really not very clear what you **want** here... What are you trying to store, what are you trying to compute? What is the actual larger problem here?

Comment: @JamesMills Sure, I have updated the first post

Comment: @sivanes That's a little clearer. What is not clear however is how this is called and with what data. When I look at your code I immediately think there is a better way to accomplish what you're *trying to do*. What I wanted you to describe is your problem in english text, rather than the technical/programming-language challenges you're trying to overcome :)

Comment: @JamesMills Ok, in English, I am basically trying to make a running, simplified version of one of those astrology match programs for practice. All the data right now - the two parameters for the self.one, self.two, etc attrubutes - is randomly generated. The method is supposed to take two attributes and evaluate their relationship by giving a score in the end, that's what `overall` is for. Since for right now I want to evaluate all the relationships the same way, I want to see how I can avoid making a separate method for each `self.___` vs `other.___` pairing I want to do.

Comment: If you want to treat *Python Objects* using *comparison operators* you could implement the ``__lt__`` and ``__eq__`` special methods. See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#

Comment: @JamesMills I will read through that, thank you

Comment: @JamesMills I honestly don't see how these methods make things easier here. The rich comparison methods seem to be more about whether the two objects are equal, greater than, less than, etc. While for something like self.one[0] I want to see if the difference between two umbers within range 1-12 is of certain value(s). And for self.one[1] if the difference is within a certain range.

Comment: @sivanes It was only an example of how you could create classes of objects that behave similarly to numbers and utilize binary operators or comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, keep an internal class list and add each object to the list when it is initialised, then have an internal function that you can call that compares one object to the rest of the created objects in the list.

```
class OurClass:
    classList = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.one = (x, y) 
        self.two = (a, z)            
        OurClass.classList.append(self)

    def ourmethod(self)
        for n in OurClass.classList:
            if n != self:
                # some stuff happens
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is meant to accomplish. Is the intention here to share data between instances of ``OurClass``?

Comment: Gives you a list of Objects, every time an object is initialised it is added to the internal class list, I've found it useful on many occasions.

Comment: IHMO I think it's better to be more explicit about this and use the *Registry Patten* and have a registry of objects. There are many libraries that do this.